# JS: replace function definition before object instantiation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, jasmine

**I have** `outerView` and `innerView` inside my require.js module. They can be described with few statements:

- `InnerView`s is instantiated on `OuterView` rendering
- `InnerView` calls `calculated` method on own instantiation
- `InnerView.calculate` method use AJAX, which is undesirable in unit tests (with jasmine)

**I need:** in my jasmine tests replace `innerView.calculate` method call with direct call to `innerView.handleResults` with hardcoded `data` argument.

**Problem:** The problem is also that in tests I have access only to `outerView`. So I need to replace `innerView.calculate` method definition before the `innerView` is instantiated.

**Question:** *How to replace `innerView.calculated` method definition before `innerView` is instantiated?*

**Code:**

```
    define(".....", function(...) {
      var innerView = Backbone.View.extend ({
        initialize: function() {
          ......
          calculate(opitons);
        },

        //I NEED TO REPLACE THIS WITH handleResults(hardcodedData)
        calculate: function(options) { 
          var $this = this;
          Utils.doSmth(options).then(
              $this.handleResults
          );
        },

        handleResults: function(data) {
          ....
        }
      });

      var outerView = Backbone.View.extend ({
        subViews: [],

        render: function() {
          subViews[0] = new innerView();
        }    
      });

      return outerView;
}
```

Comment: Can you do an if statement based on a variable? Something like :

calculate: function(options){
  if(somevar){
    innerView.handleResults();
  }else{
     // do something else..
  }
}

Comment: @StevoPerisic that's a bad idea to bring flags to app code in test purposes. Maybe other ways?

Comment: Perhaps show the jasmine test code as well

Comment: @StevoPerisic nothing special happens there. I just need to "mock" that method before I call `outerView.render()`

Comment: Ok, than innerView should be available as an object before you instantiate the new innerView in the outerView render method, what you can do is change the calculate method to point to the handleResults method right before calling render.

`innerView.calculate = innerView.handleResults;`

than call render

Comment: @StevoPerisic but if I haven't - is that impossible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking...

Comment: @StevoPerisic you says "than innerView should be available ..." (c). I just say that it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the BDD philosophy is to test *behavior*. Ask yourself, do you really want to change how your functions work in your unit tests? By providing an alternate code path, you aren't testing the actual behavior you'll see in production.

For example, what if in your `then` function you do more complex data massaging than simply calling `handleResults(...)`? You then need to bring knowledge of this logic into your unit tests so you can mock out the rest of the chain correctly.

It sounds to me like what you really need is a way of mocking the AJAX request, not a way of changing how your code works. There are several ways to accomplish this. Two of the most popular are:

- [jasmine-ajax](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax) -- jasmine-specific
- [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/) -- standalone framework for creating spies, mocks, and mock HTTP servers.

I have used Sinon.JS quite a lot for testing XHR-related code paths to great effect.

Comment: thanks! We use Sinon.JS but I don't know how to replace mthod definition with it

Comment: and again, as I understand I need reference to `innerView` obj in my test to be able to spy it methods, right? So can you provide  an example pls?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a design problem to me. You have a hard-coded dependency on the innerView type in your outerView, and you are hiding it inside a closure (aka module). Worse, that inner, hard-coded dependency is hooked up to the rest of the universe (AJAX call). You'll have to expose the inner view somehow in order to make it testable.

It seems to me that at the very least, you have to open up your outerView like this:

```
var outerView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    subViews: [],

    initialize: function (options) {
        this.innerView = innerView;
    }

    render: function() {
      subViews[0] = new this.innerView();
    }    
  });
```

That way, you can at least modify outerview.innerView in your tests before you call render.

And at that point, it is only a small additional step to actually inject the dependency in `initialize`, perhaps with a default (`this.innerView = options && options.innerView || innerView;`), if you ever feel the need.